# Void function required to return value?

Tags: c, pthreads, void, void-pointers

I wrote a function as follows which is used to create pthread:

```
void *downloadfile(void *arg)
{
  char *req_path = NULL;
  char local_path[PATH_BUFFER_SIZE];
  int returncode = 0;
  gfcrequest_t *gfr = NULL;
  FILE *file = NULL;
  int i = 0;
  
  /* Build your queue of requests here */
  for (i = 0; i < nrequests; i++) {
    // pthread mutex locking
    // doing something
    // pthread mutex unlocking

    localPath(req_path, local_path);

    file = openFile(local_path);

    gfr = gfc_create();
    gfc_set_server(&gfr, server);
    gfc_set_path(&gfr, req_path);
    gfc_set_port(&gfr, port);
    gfc_set_writefunc(&gfr, writecb);
    gfc_set_writearg(&gfr, file);

    fprintf(stdout, "Requesting %s%s\n", server, req_path);

    if (0 > (returncode = gfc_perform(&gfr))) {
      fprintf(stdout, "gfc_perform returned an error %d\n", returncode);
      fclose(file);
      if (0 > unlink(local_path))
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: unlink failed on %s\n", local_path);
    } else {
      fclose(file);
    }

    if (gfc_get_status(&gfr) != GF_OK) {
      if (0 > unlink(local_path))
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: unlink failed on %s\n", local_path);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Status: %s\n", gfc_strstatus(gfc_get_status(&gfr)));
    fprintf(stdout, "Received %zu of %zu bytes\n", gfc_get_bytesreceived(&gfr),
            gfc_get_filelen(&gfr));

    gfc_cleanup(&gfr);
    req_path = NULL;
  }
//  return 0;
}
```

I commented out the "return 0;" statement because this is a void function thus should not return any value.  But the compiler complains that

`error: control reaches end of non-void function`

If I uncomment the "return 0;" statement, the error goes away.  I am so puzzled.  How can the compiler require a void function to return value?  Could somebody please help out?

Comment: The function is't a `void` function, but a `void *` function. The return type`void` means the function doesn't return a value, the return type `void *` means the function returns a pointer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks! But then in this case how should I write the return statement?  I don't see there is any pointer I can explicitly return at the end of this function.

Comment: Then `return NULL;` makes sense.

Comment: If you don't want to return anything change the return type of your function to just `void`, or else return `NULL` which is `(void *)0` in standard definition of `stddef.h` header file.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX Thanks! How should I modify the function definition to make it a truly void function?

Comment: Just remove asterisk :) "void downloadfile(void *arg)"

Comment: If you don't want to return anything then better change `void *` to `void`. there won't be a need to have a check at the client. `void* ret = downloadfile(NULL); if(!ret)//do something `

Comment: @TruthSeeker Thanks! But isn't that void * function is the type required by pthread? I don't know whether pthread accept void function.

Comment: The function definition seems to match that which you would pass to `pthread_create`, so I doubt OP has the liberty to do so.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't aware of the use case, you can't change the function prototype. The only option you have is to return `NULL`, if not defined `((void*)0)`

Comment: @TruthSeeker Thanks! Could you consolidate your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @TruthSeeker, `NULL` is defined in several of the very common standard headers, but if the OP happens not to be including any of those already and doesn't want to add one, then their original `return 0` is fine.  The integer constant `0` is a perfectly servicable null pointer constant, per spec.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes, I second that.  But the post was regarding to have a return value or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description I assume that your function `downloadfile` is to be used as function-pointer argument in a `pthread_create` call.

So you have a basic misunderstanding. The function pointer used for `pthread_create` is **not** a function pointer to a "void function". It's a function pointer to a function that **returns a void pointer**. (BTW: You can get the return value using the `pthread_join` function if needed)

So in other other words: Your function must return a void-pointer. If you have nothing meaningful to return just use `return NULL;`

Extra details:

From https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html we have:

```
   int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
                      const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
                      void *(*start_routine)(void *),
                      void *restrict arg);
```

The interresting part here is `void *(*start_routine)(void *)` which means:

```
 void *(*start_routine)(void *)
 \----/\--------------/\------/
    |   Function ptr       |
    |   to a function   /----------\   
    |        that takes void pointer as argument
    |   and returns
/----------\
void pointer
```

So again - to use a correct function pointer argument for `pthread_create` you need a function that returns a void-pointer.

Comment: ... and the OP's original `return 0` exactly does return a null pointer.  `return NULL` is almost certainly fine too (though it depends on which headers are included), but there was nothing wrong with the original `return` statement.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Agree. And OP actually writes exactly that, i.e. that the error came when the `return 0;` was commented out. What was wrong was OPs expectation, i.e. that OP expected that it was/should be a void function.

Answer (score 3):

> because this is a void function

No it isn't. It is a function returning a `void*`. Pthreads *only* work with functions of the signature `void* f (void*)`. That's the only kind of function you can use, as per pthread library design. You don't get to chose anything else.

> error: control reaches end of non-void function

This is a nice error to get since your code without the return statement contains undefined behavior. Specifically C17 6.9.1/12 says:

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

As in, if you didn't use `return` and the caller checks the result - which will happen here inside the pthreads lib, then anything can happen. It is a bug.

If you aren't interested in returning anything from the function, you *must* `return NULL;` or the equivalent `return 0;`.

Notably, the difference between returning `void` and `void*` is fundamental C - it is something you should have studied at a much earlier stage before moving on to multi-threading, which is a more advanced topic.